# Java nested conditional parsing of CSV file

Tags: java, parsing, csv, import

If my sample data is a CSV file that looks like this:

```
a,,,b,
36,28,90,5,24
```

what would be the best way to either have something like

> myStringArray = [a, [36,28,90]], [b, [5,24]]

or

> myStringArray1 = {a,b}; // this part i can do
>   myStringArray2 = {{36,28,90}, {5,24}};

I am using Processing, which is based on Java, but my question is more about the general functionality of Java, so excuse my code formatting, if it doesn't appear java correct.

here is my import class:

```
class dTable {

  int rowCount;
  int columnCount;
  String[][] data;
  String filename;

  dTable(String _filename) {
    filename = _filename;
  }

  void load() {
    String[] rows = loadStrings(filename);
    String[] columns = split(rows[0], ',');
    rowCount = rows.length;
    columnCount = columns.length;

    //set the size of the matrix
    data = new String[rows.length][columns.length]; 

    // add column pieces into data matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      String[] colEntries = split(rows[i], ',');
      for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = colEntries[j];
      }
    }


  }
}
```

and here is my unworking attempts at a parsing class:

```
class dParse {

  String[] bMaj;
  String[][] bMin;

  dParse() {
  }

  void getList(int integer) {

    ArrayList dMaj = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList dMin = new ArrayList();

    String[][] minimums;

    String[] _rowNameMaj = table.data[0]; //get data first to match
    String[] _rowName = table.data[integer]; // get data to fill

    //get first variables
    for (int i = 0; i<_rowName.length; i++) { //iterate over 
      ArrayList tempMin = new ArrayList();
      if (trim(_rowNameMaj[i]).length() != 0) {
        dMaj.add(_rowNameMaj[i]);
      }
    }

    //place maj values from arraylist into an array
    String[] _bMaj = (String[]) dMaj.toArray(new String[0]);
    bMaj = _bMaj; //set value to global variable


    //min values
    ArrayList bigOne = new ArrayList();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<_rowName.length; i++) { //iterate over 
      ArrayList tempMin = new ArrayList();
      if (trim(_rowNameMaj[i]).length() != 0) { //check if box is not empty & set count to 0
        //tempMin = dMaj.get(i); // set inner list
        //println("maj " + count + " " + _rowNameMaj[i]);
        tempMin.add(_rowName[i]);
        count++;
        //println("min" + count + " " + tempMin);
      }
      else if (trim(_rowNameMaj[i]).length() == 0) { //if next box is empty, add to count
        count++;
        tempMin.add(_rowName[i]);
        //println("min" + count + " ");
      }
      minimums = new String[_bMaj.length][];

     /various unworking attempts below

      //place min values from arraylist into an array
      //String[] temp_bMin = (String[]) tempMin.toArray(new String[0]);
      //fl[] = append((new String(temp_bMin)), fl);

            for (int n = 0; n< bMaj.lenth; n++ ) {
       count[level]mums[n] = (String[]) toArray(new String[0]);
//        println(minimums[n]);
//      }
      tempMin.clear(); //clear temporaryList
    }

  }

  String[] getMaj() {
    return bMaj;
  }

  String[][] getMin() {
    return bMin;
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated,
Many thanks,
Dimitar

Answer (score 0):

Dimitar... Perhaps a library such as [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv) or the links to the other libraries on that page would prove useful? However, if you insist on rolling your own CSV parser, look into the [java.util.StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
class Item { 
    String name;
    List<String> values;
}

String[] names = line1.split(",");
String[] data  = line2.split(",");

List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
Item curItem = null;

for (int i=0; i<data.length, i++) 
{
    if (names[i].isEmpty())
    {
        if (curItem == null) throw "first name is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        curItem = new Item();
        items.add(curItem);
    }
    curItem.values.add(data[i]);
}
```

This uses an `Item` class to hold each item and a `List<Item>` for the whole thing.  Downgrading to use nested arrays is left as an exercise.

***Important*** If you need real CSV parsing (quoted fields, etc) you should use a CSV library to do the initial split and then apply the logic above to the results.